# pass class as parameter in Ruby

Tags: ruby, sinatra

My current sinatra router looks like this but multiple stores are on the way so i would like to replace this case with one line,

```
get_or_post "/list.json" do
  case
    when params[:store]=='storeVakanties' then return jsonp(get_data_for(Vakantie))
    when params[:store]=='storeDeelnemers' then return jsonp(get_data_for(Deelnemer))
    when params[:store]=='storeJobstudenten' then return jsonp(get_data_for(Jobstudent))
  end
end
```

if i rename my ExtJs store to the name of the activerecord class i could do something like

```
get_or_post "/list.json" do
  jsonp(get_data_for(params[:store])) #eg params[:store]='Vakantie'
end
```

but i need to pass a class, not a string.. any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to restrict the available classes, something like this would work:

```
params = { store: "Vakantie" }

[Vakantie, Deelnemer, Jobstudent].find { |c| c.to_s == params[:store] }
#=> Vakantie
```

I would probably just write a helper method and map the classes explicitly:

```
helpers do
  def store(name)
    case name
    when 'storeVakanties' then Vakantie
    when 'storeDeelnemers' then Deelnemer
    when 'storeJobstudenten' then Jobstudent
    end
  end
end

get_or_post "/list.json" do
  jsonp(get_data_for(store(params[:store])))
end
```

Comment: your first solution is good, your second not since i want to avoid the enumeration, possibility for mistakes and maintenance when adding stores, i think i will use my own solution for the moment, thanks

Answer (score 2):

In the simplest case (no namespaces) you can use:

```
Object.const_get(params[:store])
```

If you need to get namespaced constant, you can do

```
params[:store].split('::').inject(Object) {|klass, name| klass.const_get(name) }
```

For more advanced implementation have a look at the source of `constantize` method from ActiveSupport's Inflector: http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveSupport/Inflector/constantize

Answer (score 0):

You could use `eval`:

```
get_or_post "/list.json" do
  jsonp(get_data_for(eval(params[:store])))
end
```

If you’re horrified by that, you could use `const_get`:

```
Kernel.const_get(params[:store])
```

You’ll need to perform some validation, though, because it’s dangerous to allow user input to select any defined class.

Comment: Using `eval` is not the best idea, especially with variable called `params` suggesting it comes from the outer world.

Comment: Hence the “if you’re horrified” comment hehe

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution myself using ActiveSupport's constantize

```
jsonp(get_data_for(params[:store].constantize))
```

In my case security isn't an issue but i like the solution from Stefan the best so i give him the credits.